# Running two Windows Accounts Simultaneously while remote to one of the account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, user-accounts

I want one/single computer to be running two users.

The first account should be kind of restricted, like Parental Control, but when the computer boot up it should automatically Log In to this account.

The second account should start up as well but remain inaccessible unless a credentials is keyed in. And I should be able to remotely access this second account remotely through a remote access software or even windows built in remote while the first account can still use the computer.

Is it possible to do this on Windows 10, if not, then on a Linux Distro like Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows client versions (those that do not have "Server" in the name) do not support having multiple simultaneous logons.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin So is it possible for "Windows Server" to do a job like this?

Comment: You can configure a Windows Server as a Terminal Server, and permit multiple simultaneous logons/sessions. I do not believe that you can set up a server to have a "default"/automatic logon.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Is it then possible to set some sort of parental control, that blocked everything except certain Softwares, while still being able to remotely access the computer drives?

Comment: That, I don't know; my organization uses separate web security appliances rather than anything that may be inherent in Windows.